# WebRTC server stopped working

Tags: python, ubuntu, webrtc, uwsgi

My webRTC server has stopped working. Chrome highlighted this error:

```
VM238:164 WebSocket connection to 'wss://*******.com/rtc/' failed: Error during 
WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502
```

Error has happened after rebooting server (as I think). Server info - ubuntu, nginx+uwsgi, webrtc part - python.

nginx errors log:

```
2018/03/15 15:05:17 [error] 597#0: *1058 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) 
while connecting to upstream, client: ***.***.***.***, server: ********.com, request: 
"GET /rtc/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3333/rtc/", host: "********.com"
```

nginx.conf file:

```
user ****;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}

http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        server_tokens off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Unfortunately I do not know much about WebRTS. This part of the project was done before me. If you need more information, I can provide it.

Comment: Seems a connection problem. Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @lsma no proxy. And the main site (on Django) work perfectly.

Comment: So most probably there was a NodeJS program also running to handle the WebRTC server and it was not added as a service. This means you need to find where that WebRTC node server code is and start it as well. If the sever doesn't have too many node projects, I would search for the project using `locate package.json` or `grep -r "/rtc" <dir>`. Once you start the server the error should be gone.

Comment: I would also run the `history` command to find out a command which was used to run the server previously.

Comment: @VadimPavlovich when does this error occur? I mean, what are the actions in the client side that end up with this error? Are you trying to register a user? Have you already registered a user and are you trying to make a call?

Comment: @VadimPavlovich, any update/feedback on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So most probably there was a NodeJS program also running to handle the WebRTC server and it was not added as a service.

The restart has caused the service to go away

This means you need to find where that WebRTC node server code is and start it as well. If the sever doesn't have too many node projects, I would search for the project using locate `package.json` or `grep -r "/rtc" <dir>`. Once you start the server the error should be gone.

I would also run the `history` command to find out a command which was used to run the server previously

This is simply a poorly configured server